# dynamicjasper Display Static text at the end of the Report on last page

Tags: dynamic-jasper

I have a report to build where at the end of the Table I have to print "End of Statement". This static text has to be printed right after the last row of the table. I am using DynamicJasper and I need to know how can I achieve this.

```
report.addGlobalFooterVariable(cGlobal, new CustomExpression() {
    public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) 
    { 
        return "End of Statment - > "; 
    }    
    public String getClassName() {
        return String.class.getName(); 
    } 
}, tGlobal.build()); 
report.setGrandTotalLegend("");
```

Comment: Please show some of what you have done/achieved so far.

Comment: report.addGlobalFooterVariable(cGlobal, new CustomExpression() {
    public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {
    return "End of Statment - > ";
    }
    public String getClassName() {
    return String.class.getName();
    }
    }, tGlobal.build());
    report.setGrandTotalLegend("");

It does display "End of Statement" after the table, but in case if table rows end around the footer this gets printed on next page along with Table column. If somehow those columns are not printed it might be a workaround.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the source in it; in a comment it is hardly readable.

Comment: Please see the code, I have added it in the Question.